# Obtain time c++

Tags: c++, c++11, time, performancecounter, c++-chrono

I am trying to convert a Windows c++ function to a portable one.
The objective of the function is to obtain a reference cpu time in seconds. The Windows function uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, which are not portable to mac, so I have tried to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, but I do not understand how it works.

The function that I already have is the following:

```
double GetSeconds(void)
{
  double sec;
  LARGE_INTEGER Frequency, PerformanceCount;

  QueryPerformanceFrequency( &Frequency );
  QueryPerformanceCounter( &PerformanceCount );

  sec = (double)PerformanceCount.QuadPart /(double)Frequency.QuadPart;

  return(sec);
}
```

With `high_resolution_clock` I have the following code working (it returns the time that printing "Hello World" takes):

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::cout << "Hello World\n";
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
float a = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count();
```

But I do not understand why the following line does not work (I just want to obtain the start time point):

```
float a = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(start).count();
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `start` isn't a *duration*, it's a *time point*. Also note that [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) is not related to the wall clock, so getting its current value in itself doesn't really tell you that much, it's just a counter that steadily counts up.

Comment: +1.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm for more details.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg @Howard-Hinnant Thank your for your answer.
But I do not understand how to use the _duration_ or the *time_point* to obtain the current execution time.

Comment: @jl.da The execution time is the duration between `start` and `end`. If you want to get the *wall clock* (i.e. the system time) of any of those points, you have to use `system_clock` and [`to_time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) or similar.